# Why are distances in text2vec's RWMD module between 1 and -1?

Tags: r, word-embedding, text2vec

From what I understand, the dist2 RWMD feature of the great text2vec package calculates distances between matrixes as cosine distances. Wouldn't that mean 1 - (cosine similarity)? If cosine similarity runs between 0 and 1, then shouldn't that result in values between 0 and 1, too? I am not sure how to interpret negative distances in this case, and how are they different from positive distances. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The cosine between two vectors is the dot product divided by the product of the norms. Since the dot product can be negative, cosine is between 1 and -1.